# Trying to add new TextView to Bottom of Screen and have them Stacked

Tags: java, android, text

So currently I have an EditText field and a button and I want every time when that button is pushed to add the name at the bottom of the screen, but continuing to add them to the bottom of the screen rather than one line. It's currently only printing on one line and I don't know how to make the font bigger on the text that is being added. Sorry for the dumb question. This is what I have in the main file and the XML bc it wouldn't let me post right below it

```
    package com.example.bryce.
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.content.
    public class MainActivity extends 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LinearLayout mLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        final EditText mEditText=findViewById(R.id.StudentNameEdt);
        final Button mButton=findViewById(R.id.insertButton);
        TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("New TExt");
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
            }
        });



    }
    private TextView createNewTextView(String text)
    {
        final LinearLayout mLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        String newLine=System.getProperty("line.separator");
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mLayout.getLayoutParams();
        final TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("New texT:: "+text+newLine);

        return textView;
    }
    }
And here is the XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="900dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NewClassTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Welcome!"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WelcomeAgain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NewClassTitle"
            android:text="Fill out the Form Below to Register"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ClassNumEdt"
            android:layout_width="324dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="222dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Class 
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/insertButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/StudentView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/NewClassTitle"
            android:text="Insert"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/StudentNameEdt"
            android:layout_width="337dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Student Name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Could you show me the design you are trying to achieved? I guess this problem can be easily solved by recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` orientation appears to be `horizontal`. It should be `vertical` where you to expect the lines to be added below.

That being said, consider using a `RecyclerView` for the task.

Comment: Would I replace ScrollView?

Comment: Well, that pretty much depends on the UX you're trying to achieve. The problem in your configuration is only that when many items are inserted, the buttons will be out of the screen when/if the user scrolls down. If that's OK with you, then there's no harm with using `ScrollView`.